# How do I access the MAAS web interface?

Tags: cloud, maas

i installed maas as the steps guided me but in the end i dont know how to access to maas web interface ?

Next steps
Now you have a working MAAS. You can log into the web interface at the following address, substitute the hostname for your machine of course:

"http://hostname/MAAS"

this step.. I installed ubuntu 12.04 via vmware on my windows 7 . Can anyone help how to access this step . and where to write this ? in my browser it says but when i write to my browser it doesnt opens .

Answer (score 2):

The hostname is the IP address of the machine MAAS is installed on. In the terminal on the MAAS machine run ifconfig and find the IP address for that device. Then replace `hostname` above with the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I got mine to work by opening the port for the MAAS webpage in my firewall. MAAS seems to automatically set to the webpage at `localhost:5240/MAAS` using port 5240 which may not be open on your firewall if your firewall is enabled. At the time I was using the **ufw** firewall so I used the following command on the server to open the port:

```
sudo ufw allow 5240
```

If you are running at different firewall you will have to open up the port for that firewall.

However if you are still using the ufw firewall enter the following command

```
sudo ufw verbose
```

If your firewall is active you should see something like this

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----

5240                       ALLOW       Anywhere  
5240                       ALLOW       Anywhere
```

At this point you can see that the ports are open to your LAN. (If you want to reach your MAAS web page outside of your LAN you will have to do some port forwarding with your router. This may also however come at the cost of security).

At this point try to connect to the web page with your client using your localhost IP. (you can find the ip of your server using the command `ifconfig` and searching for the IP next to `inet addr`)

If you want to see if it works on a text browser first you can install the lynx browser for Ubuntu and type in the `g` command to insert the server URL

```
sudo apt-get install lynx
```

Either way insert this into the browser you choose and you should be able to login

```
http://localhostIP:5240/MAAS
```

If none of this works check out the page below and search for "Can’t find MAAS webpage"

https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/troubleshooting.html